# How to Catch Particular DB error in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server-2005, exception

In my SP (Sql Server 2005) I'm raising an error using

```
Raiserror ('No Records Fetched' , 16 ,1)
```

I want to catch this particular error in ASP.NET.. how do I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ought to do it:

```
catch(SqlException ex) {
    if(ex.Errors.Count > 0 && ex.Errors[0].Message == "No Records Fetched" && ex.Errors[0].Class == 16) {
        // your error
    }
}
```

However, the errors collection may also contain low-severity `print` statement messages and other junk from previous statements. It's up to you whether you want to write more sophisticated filtering code to eliminate them.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst Christian Hayter's answer is correct, an alternative would be to use [sp_addmessage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178649%28SQL.90%29.aspx) to create your own customer error number which relates specifically to this problem. This would save you having to parse the error message.